# JFileChooser extension

Tags: java, swing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I need to display the file name without the extension in JFileChooser(open mode). How?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9189791/i-need-to-display-the-file-name-without-the-extension-in-jfilechooseropen-mode)

Can anyone tell me how switch off extensions in view openDialog ?
I want see only name file without his extension in this view.
thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can use a custom writen javax.swing.filechooser.FileView that you set in your filechooser

Answer (score 1):

The *Customizing the File View* section in the Java Tutorial includes an example of defining your own `FileView` object to control how the files are displayed in a `JFileChooser`.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html

Override the `FileView.getName()` method to display a customized name for each file.

Download the FileChooserDemo2 demo from this web page to try the example and change method `ImageFileView.getName()` to return the filename with the file extension removed.