# I need to display the file name without the extension in JFileChooser(open mode). How?

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I use 'JFileChooser' in open mode. I need to display the 'file name' field without the extension. 
How??
I know the FileView. It remove extensions in file system's files, but it leaves the expansion in selected file in the field 'File name'
[explanation](http://saveimg.ru/show-image.php?id=75ff6a5e11823f4ac834325d89165e83)

This is my FileView code:

```
public class JQSFileView extends FileView{
@Override
    public String getName(File file){
        return FilenameUtils.removeExtension(file.getName());
    }
}
```

I use this:

```
        fc.addPropertyChangeListener(JFileChooser.SELECTED_FILE_CHANGED_PROPERTY, new PropertyChangeListener()
    {
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt)
        {

            File selectedFile = fc.getSelectedFile();
            String path = selectedFile.getPath();
            path=FilenameUtils.removeExtension(path);
            fc.setSelectedFile(new File(path));

        }
    });
```

But JFileChooser return not right file name, and cursor always jump to up when I select some file

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @AlexK  This is not a duplicate of that question.  That question could be solved using a `FileView`, whereas this OP says they already use that, and are referring to a different field in the chooser.

Comment: @Serge, which code? my FileView? This:

Comment: @AndrewThompson, look how work all editor and other programs. I use FileFilter with one extension and user know what extension he will get

Comment: *"I use FileFilter with one extension"*  A-ha, suddenly it makes perfect sense.  Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The underlying reason is that the ui doesn't use the view's name as text in the name field. Which may or may but be a good idea, don't know. If you really want that, you can do so manually, either in a subclass of JFileChooser or in a PropertyChangeListener, here's an override:

```
    fc = new JFileChooser() {

        @Override
        public void setSelectedFile(File file) {
            super.setSelectedFile(file);
            ((BasicFileChooserUI) getUI()).setFileName(getName(file));
        }

    };
    fc.setFileView(new MyView());
```

**Edit**

outch ... hadn't expected so much mis-behaviour of the ui :-( Problem is that all the actions re-create a file object based on the content of the textField (instead of using the selectedFile property of the chooser) Now if that string has the extension trimmed, the file isn't found. The only way out would be to replace the actions ... which might not work.

In summary, this answer is useless, sorry.

Comment: It is funny, but now files open only by double-click. If I choose file, then click button "Open", it don't work. And now I don't know how correct it